# Vim --- Read from an External Command, Inserting Right Where the Cursor Is

Tags: vim

`:r !program` opens a new line, inserts my program's output and then inserts a line after it.
I simply want to insert the output right where the cursor is without that additional mess.

I figured I can:

1. Run a before macro

   ```
    mai^M^[`a 

    "Mark where I'm at, insert a line and go back
   ```
2. Run my command

   ```
   :r !echo -ne "line1\nline2\nline3"
   ```
3. Run an after macro (cleanup the lines)

   ```
   $mb:j!^M`a:j!^M`b 

   "Go to the end of inserted outpu
   "Mark it b
   "Join with the next line
   "Go to the first mark
   "Delete the inserted newline with :j!
   "Go to the second mark
   ```

How can I combine this into a single command?
I'd like to be able to do:

```
:Readhere !echo -ne "line1\nline2\nline3"
```

where :Readhere would be my custom command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do what you want. (You don't need the `!`)

```
command! -nargs=1 ReadHere exec 'normal! i' . system(<q-args>)
```

This creates a command called `ReadHere` that takes everything as a quoted argument and passes it directly to the system command. Then we use exec to insert everything in normal mode. (This might not be robust enough)

---

Example: Starting buffer is

```
one two three
```

Running `:ReadHere echo -ne "line1\nline2\nline3"` where the cursor is on the `w` produces

```
one tline1
line2
line3wo three
```